# Dell Inspiron with NVIDIA GPU overheating while gaming on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dell, games, overheating

I recently got a Dell Inspiron with a dedicated GeForce MX150.

I'm using `nvidia-driver-440` and everything works fine, except that while playing Underlords with *best looking* settings, CPU and GPU temperatures start to go over 95C and eventually the laptop dies (probably triggering a security measure for high temperatures).

This is the first time I'm using this laptop, so I'm not sure if this happens in another distros or Windows.

I installed `tlp` but haven't seen any differences.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, the power given to the one square inch is 25 Watts. The heat radiation with or without fans should be efficient than now. 1) float your laptop ) send cool air 3) put an extra radiator on the aluminium body and etc. Anyway, you should force to overcome the heat or your laptop dies.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same GeForce MX150 in my Dell Ubuntu Series laptop and faced the same issue. I was able to fix the gaming problem by adopting the following configurations (number 1 is mandatory, the others probably are optional):

Configuration 1: in the PowerMizer section from the NVIDIA X Server Settings, there is a dropdown menu with its Preferred Mode options. Please set it to "Prefer Maximum Performance"

[image]

Configuration 2: still at the NVIDIA X Server Settings, you can also set the "Image Settings" dropdown in the OpenGL Settings section to "High Performance"

[image]

Configuration 3: since that you mentioned that you have tlp installed, you can open a terminal window and type

```
sudo tlp true
```

it switches tlp to the battery mode, which (I guess) reduces the power consuption by lowering the clockdown and consequently reducing the overheating.

As I mentioned, probably only configuration 1 is mandatory. Configurations 2 and 3 alone helped me with some games, but didnt solved the issue for all of them, so I'm using the 3 together. But you can check if only configuration 1 is enough for your needs.