# Nvidia proprietary driver causing overheat

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, overheating, nvidia-settings

I've a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 lts and having nvidia mx150 as my GPU. When I watch an HD video or do some GPU dedicated tasks like animation or deep learning, I see my core temperatures rising above 85°C. The nvidia software is version 460.
Please help.

Comment: I only have questions that need adding to the question ;-) Are there other drivers in the driver selection? Did you try any of these? Is this with our without fans? If not did you see any errors in the logs regarding fan control?  and tp top it of: did https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222402/dell-inspiron-with-nvidia-gpu-overheating-while-gaming-on-ubuntu-18-04 not work for you?

Comment: It seriously looks like a HARDWARE problem if I see this topic on nvidia forums; https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/geforce-graphics-cards/5/262139/geforce-mx150-performancethrottling-issues/

Comment: april fool ? The temperature can be as a high as 97°C. Above this temperature the processes get throttled. Don't find anything wrong with it.

Comment: I have the exact same nvidia mx150, and am suffering from the exact same issue. Only difference is I used version 525 as it is the latest.